# Fetch() hangs in RSQLite for large query

Tags: r, sqlite

I am using RSQLITE in R to build database and do 'JOIN' operation and extracting the rows using:

```
    res<-dbSendQuery(con," SELECT DISTINCT all_transcript.transcript1 from temp LFET OUTER JOIN....")
```

There are in total 16 JOIN operations. 
I verify that the command above is working fine as fetch(res) returns 500(default) number of rows. Also, it works for only limited number of rows. But it hangs when I provide fetch(res,n=-1) to extract all the number of lines. Any idea?
I just gave fetch(res,n=4000) and its not responding.

sessionInfo of the R:

```
sessionInfo():
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
[7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] RSQLite_0.11.1 DBI_0.2-5
```

Comment: The sqlite data bases are accessible from the command line (on linux); does your query work there? Might as well provide the output of `sessionInfo()`, the memory available on your machine, and the size of the object you're expecting to have returned...

Comment: It didnt strike to me to run it from command line. I am running it now and I am expecting it to take some time (I will update it). Though I have edited the sessionInfo in the question. I am running it on cluster so, it has memory of more than 500G and I am expecting the size of the object at least 40G.

Comment: I ran it on command line (on linux) and seems like it didnt work at all. It was not responding there as I didnt see any memory usage.

Comment: Joins become very expensive when there many of them. Post your sql query - may be it can be tweaked. How many rows do you expect to get overall? Maybe there is a limit on DB side like log or cache size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: 16 JOINS for important query means your query and/or database is not designed well. Ways to improve - do less joins:

1. Create summary table(s), denormalised tables
2. Tune you query by applpying filters to data as early in query plan as possible, so less data joined
3. Keep db on more powerful server and use another DB engine, and make R app query that DB and just store results in sqlite

There is a lot of research you can do on query optimisation and performance tuning too.